# How does one reference a module as a param in JSDocs

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

Given a module like:

```
/** Config module
 * @module Config
 */
export default class Config {
...
```

How do I specify a link to the Config module when specified as a param?

```
/**
 * Foo
 * @module Foo
 */
export default class Foo {
    /**
     * Create a new instance
     * @constructor
     * @param {Config} config - the config
     */
    constructor(config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
```

I cannot seem to get the Config to register as a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple prefix with `module:`

See below

```
/**
 * Foo
 * @module Foo
 */
export default class Foo {
    /**
     * Create a new instance
     * @constructor
     * @param {module:Config} config - the config
     */
    constructor(config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
```